# Set resistance to Two Finger Scrolling

Tags: xorg, touchpad

I'm still using the synaptics driver because of the lack of configurability in libinput (the speed of the pointer is bad for small and large distances, there is no coasting, I need to limit the size of the touchpad or my laptop will recognize areas outside, and I'm used to setting the scrolling speed too).

So, the synaptics driver being so configurable, I would like to know if it's possible to have some sort of **resistance before Two Finger Scrolling begins** in the synaptics driver. For this I have two reasons:

1. When I use two finger tap as a right-click, many times it scrolls first and then opens the menu. If I right click a link in the web browser, the link escapes from underneath the cursor first, and I have to try again. I have tried setting the right-click to three fingers, but then I have to move the hand a lot more.
2. The lack of some resistance makes horizontal scrolling very annoying: it should not begin scrolling horizontally until the user is explicitly moving the fingers sideways. That is the default in Windows, I don't remember how it works in libinput.

Comment: I don't know much about synaptics, wanted to note you may want to remove libinput tag. Regarding your 1 and 2 points for libinput though: 1. I don't see this behavior on libinput, I guess it delays scroll a tiny bit until it's clear whether a user wanted a 2-finger tap or to scroll 2. this one is not a problem because libinput sticks scroll to X or Y axis unless a user is explicitly trying to scroll diagonally *(this behavior was merged into upstream 2 or 3 years ago I think)*